Extract information from not structured XML-string
I'm trying to extract information with SQL from a XML column which looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Advertentie>
  <Filter>
    <Woninglabels Enabled="True" Priority="1">
      <Woninglabel Id="1" Type="Huishoudgrootte" Enabled="True" SeqNumber="1" SortDirection="DESC" Min="0" Max="99" Text="" />
      <Woninglabel Id="2" Type="Leeftijd" Enabled="True" SeqNumber="2" SortDirection="DESC" Min="0" Max="999" Text="" />
    </Woninglabels>
  </Filter>
</Advertentie>

XML
The information I need are the Min and Max values for every Woninglabel Id (just pasted two, but there are over 10 Woninglabels). The problem I'm running into is that all the information is between just two "<" ">".
I tried using the .value() method, but soon ran into the problem that all the information is just between two of those "<" ">".
select TOP 100 ic,
CAST(ic AS XML).value('(<Advertentie><Filter><Woninglabels Enabled="True" Priority="1"><Woninglabel Id="1" Type="Huishoudgrootte" Enabled="True" SeqNumber="1" SortDirection="DESC" Min=")[1]','int(2)') AS Name
from adv

And got this error:
error

Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

sql database on a Windows server

SQL is a language supported by dozens of different products, even on Windows. Perhaps you mean MS SQL Server?

Yes that's what I mean

Please do not use images, use code formatting, tablemarkdown and quotes text.

Then please correct your tags to include sql-server

You need to use nodes function to shred down each label and then fetch the attributes that you need. value method is useful there, attributes are accessed using @name syntax. Why not peruse the Microsoft XML documentation, it should be clearly stated there. BTW, not sure why you think this is unstructured data

not structured XML is a bit of a contradiction when talking about XML and doesn't explain anything. By definition XML has a structure. What you posted is very well structured, with every element and attribute having a specific name instead of the dreaded name="Price" value="1,234" type="good_luck_parsing_this". You can use OPENXML to parse it and extract the attributes as columns, the .query method and XPATH to extract specific parts. Check OPENXML examples in the docs

Thanks for your help @siggemannen. It looked not structured for me, but I'm also not very familiar with retrieving data from xml.

I'll dive into this @PanagiotisKanavos many thanks. Also for explaining the structure of this xml.

This is very well structured XML. Unstructured would be something like name="Price" value="1,234" type="good_luck_parsing_this". There are several ways to query XML. You can use .value to extract specific values based on an XPath ... path, you can use query to extract elements as XML, or use .nodes() to extract data as a rowset that can be part of a larger query.
If the XML was stored in a variable, you could use this to extract the label data :
select 
    a.value('./@Id','int') as Id,
    a.value('./@Type','nvarchar(20)') as Type,
    a.value('./@Enabled','bit') as Enabled,
    a.value('./@SeqNumber','int') as SeqNumber,
    a.value('./@Min','int') as Min,
    a.value('./@Max','int') as Max
from @xml.nodes('//Woninglabel') x(a)
---
Id  Type    Enabled SeqNumber   Min Max
1   Huishoudgrootte 1   1   0   99
2   Leeftijd    1   2   0   999

Or this to extract just one label's data :
select 
    a.value('./@Id','int') as Id,
    a.value('./@Type','nvarchar(20)') as Type,
    a.value('./@Enabled','bit') as Enabled,
    a.value('./@SeqNumber','int') as SeqNumber,
    a.value('./@Min','int') as Min,
    a.value('./@Max','int') as Max
from @xml.nodes('//Woninglabel') x(a)
where a.value('./@Id','int')=1
---
Id  Type    Enabled SeqNumber   Min Max
1   Huishoudgrootte 1   1   0   99

With a table column whose type isn't XML, you can use a CTE or subquery to first parse the text into XML. You could put this "shredding" code into a view too, to reduce the complexity of the query
declare @t table (OuterID bigint identity primary key,x nvarchar(max));
insert into @t values (@txt);


with parsed as (
 select *, cast(x as xml) xx1 from @t
)
select OuterID,
    a.value('./@Id','int') as Id,
    a.value('./@Type','nvarchar(20)') as Type,
    a.value('./@Enabled','bit') as Enabled,
    a.value('./@SeqNumber','int') as SeqNumber,
    a.value('./@Min','int') as Min,
    a.value('./@Max','int') as Max
from parsed 
cross apply xx1.nodes('//Woninglabel') x(a)
---
OuterID Id  Type    Enabled SeqNumber   Min Max
1   1   Huishoudgrootte 1   1   0   99
1   2   Leeftijd    1   2   0   999

Those columns can be used for filtering, just like any other column :
with parsed as (
 select *, cast(x as xml) xx1 from @t
),
labels as (
    select OuterID,
        a.value('./@Id','int') as Id,
        a.value('./@Type','nvarchar(20)') as Type,
        a.value('./@Enabled','bit') as Enabled,
        a.value('./@SeqNumber','int') as SeqNumber,
        a.value('./@Min','int') as Min,
        a.value('./@Max','int') as Max
    from parsed 
    cross apply xx1.nodes('//Woninglabel') x(a)
)
select * from labels 
where SeqNumber=2

